# When exec (i / j) and (i % j), jvm will do one calc or two?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

I used `javap` command to make bytecodes, and there are two instructions: idiv and irem.I know that div's result store in different register, will jvm only exec div opeartion once?

```java
int i = 10;
int a = i / 4;
int b = i % 4;
```

bytecode:

```
Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: bipush        10
         2: istore_1
         3: iload_1
         4: iconst_4
         5: idiv
         6: istore_2
         7: iload_1
         8: iconst_4
         9: irem
        10: istore_3
        11: return
```

Comment: HotSpot has a +PrintAssembly option so you can check

Answer (score 2):

If you were interpreting byte codes, the JVM would treat the `idiv` and `irem` as separate (bytecode) instructions and execute them separately.

If you are talking about code that has been compiled to native code, it will depend on:

- whether there is a native instruction on your execution platform that combines division and remainder<sup>1</sup>, and
- whether the JIT compiler makes use of the capability of that instruction.

You can use the `-XX+PrintAssembly` option to check what the JIT compiler generates.  (You also need to supply `-XX:UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`: see the `java` manual entry.)

Note that the answer is liable to be hardware and Java version dependent.

---

<sup>1 - The 32 and 64 bit `IDIV` instructions for `x86` and `x86-64` do.</sup>